# thrift node javascript namespace

Tags: javascript, node.js, conflict, thrift

I seem to be experiencing a node/thrift namespace conflict.

```
Foo.thrift
...
struct Error {
    1: i32 code,
    2: string message
}
...
```

which generates the following file via `thrift --gen js:node Foo.thrift` (thrift v0.9.0)

```
Foo_types.js
...
Error = module.exports.Error = function(args) {
  this.code = null;
  this.message = null;
  if (args) {
    if (args.code !== undefined) {
      this.code = args.code;
    }
    if (args.message !== undefined) {
      this.message = args.message;
    }
  }
};
Error.prototype = {};
Error.prototype.read = function(input) {
...
```

I include the module in node

```
var FooTypes = require('./../gen-nodejs/Foo_types')
```

I seem to run into a namespace conflict with javascript's Error object

```
callback(new Error("Couldn't find profile"));
```

In the callback, it shows that I have an object with `code` and `message` vs a plain old JS Error containing "message" even though I didn't ask for `FooTypes.Error`.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Error

Has anyone else ran into this? How do I make reference to the plain JS Error?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're missing namespace declaration. Try this:

```
# Foo.thrift file content
namespace js Foo
...
struct Error {
    1: i32 code,
    2: string message
}
...
```

Then your thrift object would be `Foo.Error`.